# Discrete random variable that cannot be modeled in the classical probability model

Tags: probability, random-variables

In the last test I took, there was a question:

> Provide an example of a discrete random variable that cannot be modeled in the classical probability model.

I know that the classical probability model means that all elementary events are equally probable. Hence, since a random variable is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, I want this function to have at least two different values. Therefore, an example could simply be a variable with a Bernoulli distribution, where $p = \frac{1}{4}$, because there are two events and each has a different probability.

However, I am not sure if this is right. Is what I wrote correct?

Comment: In that case, you could model it with $4$ events, each with probability $\frac 14$.  Try something like three events with probabilities $\frac 12$, $\sqrt 2 -1 $, and $2-\sqrt 2 -\frac 12$.   Or maybe just $\sqrt 2 -1, 2-\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @lulu I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Your variable with a Bernoulli distribution, where $p=\frac14$ would not be a good counterexample: take an urn with $1$ red ball and $3$ blue balls and look at the probability of drawing a red (assuming all balls are of equal probability).  Indeed any finite collection of events each with rational probabilities can be modelled with a simple counting probability model.

Comment: @Henry So Bernoulli with $p = \sqrt{2} - 1$ works. Everything is clear, thank you."